# CFBundleIdentifier Collision Error

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, cfbundleidentifier

I am submitted to the Apple Store through Xcode 8 and I'm getting this error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application bundle ID is actually 'com.foo.StickerPackExtension'. That should be the ID of the extension only, not the app itself.